# Showing classes only to members in parent package - java

Tags: java, oop, package, access-modifiers

I'm trying out something weird and don't know whether this is possible.

I have a class Foo1 in package a.x (a.x.Foo1).
I need methods inside this class to be accessed by other classes which are a.Foo2 and a.y.Foo3.

However, this should not be accessed by all classes outside package a (eg: b.Foo4, org.Foo5, etc.)

Can I achieve this in java? If yes, how can I do so?

Comment: Don't specify the access modifier, this will make it [package private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Then its only accessible inside a.x package,

Comment: Yes, you can only access it from within the package. As far as I know, there's no hierarchy in the packages system in Java.